# Tried joining channel but our org, isn't among the orgs of the channel

Tags: hyperledger-fabric

While adding a new organization to the hyper ledger fabric network, the peer logs shows the below error.

> [gossip/service] updateAnchors -> ERRO 327 Tried joining channel
>   mychannel but our org( org4), isn't among the orgs of the channel:
>   [org1 org2 org3] , aborting.

And a warning like below.

> [gossip/gossip] Gossip -> WARN 3d9 Failed obtaining gossipChannel of
>   [99 104 45 99 111 109 109 111 110] aborting.

Hyper ledger Fabric version : v1.1.0

Dynamic leader election properties added into peer-base.

I was following the instructions [here.](http://hyperledger-fabric.readthedocs.io/en/release-1.1/channel_update_tutorial.html)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because the peer is being joined with the genesis block (which knows about the original members of the channel, but not the new members), these log statements are emitted.

Usually, these statements will be benign; so long as the peer is able to retrieve and commit blocks, you may ignore these messages. Eventually, the peer will receive the config block which adds its org, and gossip networking will begin working properly again.

This is a known issue, and in the future, we hope to allow peers to be joined to a channel using the latest configuration block, and not only the genesis block.

Comment: Thanks Jason. That make sense. I was wondering, in anyway whether this can affect the peer event hub?    I am having an API for network, [Fabric Altoros API](https://github.com/Altoros/fabric-rest) and it is unable to connect t the peer event hub newly added organization. I don't have any other error apart from this in peer logs. Any idea?

Comment: API was not connecting because of a weird issue. While creating event hub the end point of newly added organization will be converted to small letters. I was having the Capital in the organization name like Org3 and the endpoint of event hub is converted something like peer0.org3.example.com. I added the organization with all small case and it worked!!!!